# Stop linq from caching tables

Tags: c#, linq

when a new entity in my database is created and then i request a table from the datacontext the new entity does not appear.
is linq caching the table and returning the cached version? if so how do i stop linq from doing this.

```
DALConnector.Dc.Order.InsertOnSubmit(NewOrder);
DALConnector.Dc.SubmitChanges();
```

now i click a button that shows a form with a gridview on it databound to DALConnector.Dc.Order which doesn't show the new order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you rebinding the grid?  It does not cache the result, so I am not sure why that is an issue.  You have to requery the context to get the new record...  Or, if you are rebinding an object's records (like you are binding customers), you could get away with ensurihg the order is added to the Orders collection in the customer object, and not having to requery.

So if you are binding in this way:

```
grid.DataSource = customer.Orders;
```

You would only get the new order back if you did:

```
customer.Orders.Add(newOrder);
dc.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(newOrder);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

And then, you could bind customer.Orders directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq2Sql `DataContext` does not cache the complete Table, it only has a cache of the retrieved entities for change tracking purposes. If you would use a new DataContext for querying after you have inserted the order, your result will probably be the same.

AS you are using Linq2Sql, which can only be used with SQL Server, I recommend firing up the SQL Server Profiler and check if a real insert statement is submitted to the database in the first place.

Check your dbml, are you using runtime insert or a stored procedure for `Order`?

Also check if you're not swallowing any Exceptions the DataContext may raise on `SubmitChanges()`.

If this does not help, please add your query code so we can verify it also.